# What's the safest way to write loads of data / SQL to a text file?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm facing an issue with query / data integrity.

I'm reading loads of data (many gigabytes) from a MySQL database, processing them using PHP, to re-insert them into the same database in completely different tables. It's a one-run conversion from an old data structure to a new one, where tons of values need on the fly modification.

`SELECT FROM x` -> `modify in PHP` -> `INSERT INTO y` is *way* too slow. That takes around 1 second per 1000 records, and we're talking many many millions here. That's why I decided to export every `INSERT` into a text/sql file.

But, what's the safest way to go here? The data is everything from booleans to BLOB's. I can't really be sure of what's in it and what's not, but everything needs to get back into place appropriately, including quotes, slashes, etc.

How can I escape without any data loss?

Comment: If you use prepared statements you don't need to escape anything.

Comment: How am I going to use prepare statements in an SQL file? I'm using prepared statements now, and that's why it's taking over a millisecond to insert. Doesn't do the job. Please read my question again.

Comment: For a data set that big, you should really consider using an ETL tool.

Comment: Using an ETL tool with my current set of transformation rules is going to take longer than manually inserting all records I fear. 

I really think exporting to an SQL file (or CSV, for that matter) is my only viable solution.

Comment: It's probably better to use an automatic way rather than put it all in an sql file. That way you can distinguish the data allowing you to escape the data. Maybe use a faster language if you know any? Like C/C++ or Java?

Comment: PHP isn't the bottleneck here, it's going to the database for all new records that's taking so long. A millisecond per query is not very long, and I don't think executing it using C would be much faster. It's just the quantity that's biting me.

Comment: Yes @Sherlock you're right, the database is the bottle neck because you are communicating with it over the network and every new com-connection & message passing takes a while to send/receive/execute.

Comment: Is there any chance of localising the database and PHP server on your own PC/server for faster processing, thus removing it from the network environment (to a certain degree)?

Comment: I've benchmarked that, but that reduces the total running time from about 200 hours to 100. I need something more substantial, as this conversion should run in max 48 hours. (But 48 would leave absolutely no room for mistakes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use prepared statements to avoid the need to escape the data.

The queries you create for the prepared statements can be concatenated and executed as a group, instead of having one execute call for each row.

The code that creates, groups & concatenates SQL statements together should allow you to easily choose the number of statements concatenated in a group so you can experiment with 100 statements in one exec call vs. 1000 statements in one exec call.

The results should be much better.

Comment: How would I identify the different statements when parameterizing? I might be able to concatenate 1000 query's and just add (n * 1000) parameters, but that sounds like a very, very tricky way of doing this. I can never be sure all data lands in the right spot.

Comment: You can either use unnamed parameters and add push necessary data into an array which results in you having n*1000 place-holders and an array of length n*1000 (it doesn't even matter if n is constant between the 1000 SQL calls).

Comment: Or you could use named parameters and prefix all named parameters with a row identifier such as the [spl_object_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php), and push all parameters into an array under the same key.

Comment: Still feels very tricky compared to separate statements or complete queries in an SQL or CSV file, to be honest... I'll keep this in mind if other tracks lead to dead ends though.

Comment: Unfortunately blobs can have `EOF` characters in them, text blocks can have quotes and if you're not careful about escaping them when writing to file you're gonna have corrupt data.

Comment: The number of columns is limited, so I'm trying to find a way to copy the BLOB's and other 'fields of potential danger' seperately (using INSERT INTO SELECT or something)...

Comment: You can `base64_encode` everything in columns with "tricky" content and write the insert statements using `base64_decode` but this adds a sensible ammount of computation.

Comment: That'll probably consume more time than the whole process takes now, but it's worth trying. Thanks again.